# How to execute this Postgres SQL

Tags: postgresql

This should be a simple SQL Server query, i am new to PostGres, i am not sure what is the error, if there is a documentation, please point, i will follow up on that too

```
declare 
    Vin VARCHAR(10) := 'WBY7Z4C5&J';
begin
   SELECT false as isresultempty, v1.*, '' AS "message"
    FROM pd.vehicle v1
    WHERE v1.maskedvin = cast(Vin AS CHARACTER(10))
        AND v1.modelyyyy =  2018
        AND vinChangeCd <> 'D'
        AND v1.circularnumber <> 'INTM';
end
```

I keep getting this error

SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "false"
Position: 61
Where: invalid type name "false as isresultempty"

**update after changing this sql**
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "VARCHAR"
Position: 16

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I think it tries to declare a variable `SELECT` of type `false as isresultempty`. Don't you need a `BEGIN` after your variable declarations before actually executing queries?

Comment: @gmb - i am trying to run a sql which reads from a varible.

Comment: @Bergi  i tried to add begin and end. same issue

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html: Postgres has long but good documentation

Comment: `declare` goes before `begin`. But even so, you have a problem, because a `do` block cannot return anything. What are you actually trying to do? Maybe you want a function instead of an anonymous block?

Comment: @GMB I have changed the SQL, sorry that was copy paste. the above SQL in  SQL server wil lreturn the rows from the vehicle table.

Comment: I am trying to do the same, i understand , i will be using a function later. but i do not want to create that for now.

Comment: If you want to execute PL/pgSQL in SQL, use the `DO` statement.